# VBA - Loop through Controls on a form and read the value

Tags: vba

I would like to loop through controls on a form and read the value. However the Value and Checked properties are not available. My question is, how can I read the value of a control (in this case a checkbox) when I loop through them?

```
Dim Ctrl as Control

For Each Ctrl In frmMaintenance.Controls

    If Left(Ctrl.Name, 7) = "chkType" And **Ctrl.Value = True** Then            

    End if

Next Ctrl
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

loop through the controls and check the TypeName.

```
Dim c As Control


For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "CheckBox" Then
        MsgBox c.Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! I found out that I cannot put the validation of the type of control and the value on the same line.

Comment: @SQLiz that's because VBA logical operators `And`, `Or`, etc. - do not short-circuit, so the entire Boolean expression needs to be evaluatable.

Answer (score 6):

`TypeName` will work, but at the end of the day it's a string comparison.

The actual syntax for strongly-typed type checks in VBA goes like this:

```
TypeOf [object] Is [Type]
```

So:

```
Dim ctrl As Control
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        Debug.Print TypeName(ctrl), ctrl.Name, ctrl.Value
    End If
Next
```

Now, somewhat awkwardly the MSForms library is making `OptionButton` and `CheckBox` implement the same interface (not all that surprising actually), so the above condition will be `True` for both types of controls; you can filter out the `OptionButton` with another type check:

```
If TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.CheckBox And Not TypeOf ctrl Is MSForms.OptionButton Then
```

Arguably, using `TypeName` is simpler, at least in this case where `MSForms` is being annoying. But you *have* to know about `TypeOf ... Is` when you start needing to do type checks in VBA.